# Rails 4: select DOM element with dynamically generated id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dom

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following DOM structure on one of my views:

```
<tr id="post_row_<%= post.id%>">
  [...] # Truncated for brivety
  <td class="cell_content_center post_approval_section">
    [...] # Truncated for brivety
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need to update the content of the `td` with JavaScript.

In order to select it, I tried:

```
$('tr#post_row_<%= j post.id %> > td.post_approval_section').html('<%= j render(partial: "calendars/post_approval") %>');
```

but this gives me an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

As you can see, the `id` of the parent `tr` is dynamically generated.

How can I select it with JavaScript?

Comment: select it from where? how do you know which cell you need to reach?

Comment: please provide the log from server when `error 500` happened

Comment: hi you want to change the data of tr from which JavaScript function like onclick function or on doucument.ready function ?

Comment: single quotes don't get parsed by ruby, so your jquery will look exactly the same as your code, see solution below.

Comment: @dandavis I need to select the 'td' with the class 'post_approval_section' in the `tr` with the `id` 'post_row_<%= post.id%>'. There is only one of those per page. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @QubaishBhatti I need to change the data of the 'td' with the `html` JS function. Please my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotation(" ") instead of single quotes(' ') like:-

```
$("tr#post_row_<%= j post.id %> > td.post_approval_section")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but it does not seem to select any `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Use double " and #{} notation:

```
$("tr#post_row_#{post.id} td.post_approval_section")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but it does not seem to select any `td`.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will find the `tr` with id="post_row_`<%= j post.id %>`". Then inside `tr`, it will find `td` with class="post_approval_section".

```
$("tr#post_row_<%= j post.id %>").find('td.post_approval_section');
```

Comment: This will find the tr with id "post_row_<%= j post.id %>". Then inside tr with that id find td with class "post_approval_section".